# JavaScript this.window not equal to window

Tags: javascript

Consider the following top-level javascript code:

```
if (this.window === window)
    alert('same');
else
    alert('different'); // alerts: different
```

Why is this.window and window not strictly equal?  I've also tried 'this' on the rhs of the expression and get the same result.

Comment: `this.window === window` returns `true` in Chrome.

Comment: What browser are you using? Both Firefox and Chrome return `true` for `this.window === window`. Or do you have any situation with Iframes?

Comment: If you're really getting that `this !== window`, I believe you must be running the code not in the top level. If `this === window` it follows that `this.window === window` as `window.window === window`.

Comment: Aidas and Dylan were corrrect, this is an IE8 peculiarity it seeems.  (this===window returns true, this.window===window returs false)

Comment: what does ( window.window === window.window.window ) return in IE8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Internet Explorer (8.0.7600 is what I've tested), `this` with no qualifier actually resolves to the global window object. In all other browsers I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Opera), `this.window === window` in that context - and, helpfully, `this === window` as well.

Try this in IE to verify:

```
if (this === window)
  alert('same');
else
  alert('different');
```

Comment: In the example you gave, 'same' is alerted in IE8.  I think you most precisely answered my original question... that this is really a pecularity to IE8.

Comment: The way IE8 treats this kind of makes more sense to me. `this.window` seems equivalent to `window.window`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though HTML elements do not contain a pointer back to their parent window, as it does for `parentNode`.  Thus, `this.window` will return undefined when `this` is *anything* other than a `window` object.

The `window` object seems to be able to reference itself, perhaps because it is the only node high enough to "see" itself.  Thus, `window == window.window.window.window` and so on.

The idiosyncrasies between browsers seem to do with how each implements the DOM structure, and in particular, how they interpret `this` at the top-level.

Seeing as how individual HTML elements can't reference their parent window with `.window`, I don't really see a point in *ever* using `this.window`, though I'd love to be proved wrong here.

If you're working on code that involves manipulating objects across two different windows, I would suggest assigning your new window to a variable, e.g. `var newWin = window.open(...)` and subsequently using this variable to reference new objects.

Comment: Extra bit on native JavaScript code: provided `this === window` in the current scope, `function t(){return this};`; `t() === window`, `(x = new t()) === x` (not `window`).

Comment: I believe the handling of `this` is defined rigidly for the top level; I know that at least Processing.js uses `this` instead of `window`, apparently because it's shorter (I asked because it surprised me when I saw it). In the global scope, `this === window` should always be true.

Comment: @Chris: If you're trying to access the global object then you should use `this` rather than `window` if you want your code to run in non-browser environments. It's not true that `window` and the global object are precisely the same thing, although for most purposes in browsers they can be thought of as being so.

Comment: @Tim: I suppose that makes sense; however, Processing.js is targeting only browsers (due to its nature, using `<canvas>`, etc.)

Comment: @Jeff - I would upvote this, but I don't have enough cred yet. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Works here...

http://jsfiddle.net/rygar/DQYdk/

Comment: He said it was "top level javascript code", so your first answer was correct and your statement that you were wrong is wrong. It *does* work and is true.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` equals `window` in global context.

Comment: ... and so `this.window === window` as `window` is a global variable - `window.window === window`. `window.window.window === window` ;-)