# What is the difference between window and this.window, in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at a complex bit of JavaScript, which is doing all sorts of runtime/dynamic manipulation of objects and scripts. In the process, I'm learning all sorts of minutiae about Javascript and its idiosyncrasies.

This one has me stumped, though. Is there ever a situation where

```
window !== this.window; //true
```

In other words, when would you ever write this.window instead of straight out window?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180013/javascript-this-window-not-equal-to-window

Comment: Yeah, it is a duplicate, but it's a good question nonetheless :)

Comment: @jdi I'm not entirely sure the other question answers mine. Is it *only* under ie 8 that this.window !== window, and only in the global namespace?

Comment: Sure, it's true any time `this` isn't the global object. `new function () {console.log(window !== this.window)}`

Comment: @blueberryfields: I would look at all the info contained on that duplicate question. They pretty much say the same thing people are saying here about it being related to the current scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is there ever a situation where `window !== this.window; //true`"*

Sure, whenever `this` refers to an object without a `.window` property or with a `.window` property that doesn't point to the global object *(assuming a browser environment where `window` is the global)*.

> *"...when would you ever write `this.window` instead of straight out `window`?*

When `this` refers to an object where a `.window` property is anticipated not being a reference to the global.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is not implicitly searched for names in javascript like it is in C++ and java.

in javascript, referring to something `foo` instead of `this.foo` or `someobject.foo`, tries, in order, any `var`-declared variables, then the global namespace.

`this.var` looks up only members of `this` (and its prototype, and the prototype's prototype and so on)

at the top level in a script, `this` refers to the default global namespace, which is the `window` object, and that's where you stay until you call a method with `foo.meth()`.  `window` contains, oddly enough, a member called `window` which points to itself.  So you can generally go:

`window.window.window.window.location = "some_url"`

if you like.  In fact an awful lot of the names that you assume are "just there" are members of the global object, e.g.

`Object === window.Object`

If you like you can say

`var window;`

to declare a variable called `window` which hides the global window within that block of code.  But don't do that.

I believe you can actually change what the global namespace is as well, but I don't recall how.

Comment: you can override the global namespace? O.o

Comment: actually I'm not sure about that one.  Answer amended.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a duplicate, but `this` refers to the global scope when you're in the global scope (err), and the global scope is `window`. (so `this == window` and `window.window == window` are true)

If you're in a function that's being used as a constructor, for example (`new Pie()`), `this` no longer refers to the global scope, but rather the object that is created. What `this` is really depends on where you're running code.

Comment: wouldn't this.window still resolve to the global window, in the constructor (unless it's explicitly overwritten, I'm guessing, somewhere in the constructor)?

Comment: if you call it as `new SomeConstructor()` then this will refer to the instantiation of the object, I think...it's just an example.